# How to make an association between two tables without the expect foreign keys by rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following two models:

```
User (id)
FbFriendCache(user_id,fb_user_id)
```

I would like to be able to do : @user.facebook_friends

Which would return @users from the user model

I've tried:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :fb_friends,
    :through => :fb_friend_cache,
    :foreign_key => "fb_user_id"
```

But that fails w Could not find the association.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer as I am not able to provide the documentation snippet in comments. Ryan's solution requires a tweak.

The `foreign_key` property is ignored for `has_many :through` associations. You should use `source` property instead.

> **:through**
>
> Specifies an association through which to perform the query.
>   This can be any other type of association, including other :through
>   associations. **Options for :class_name, :primary_key and :foreign_key
>   are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection.**
>
> ..
>
> **:source**
>
> Specifies the source association name used by has_many
>   :through queries. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the
>   association. has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions will
>   look for either :subscribers or :subscriber on Subscription, unless a
>   :source is given.

Following solution should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fb_friend_cache
  has_many :facebook_friends, :through => :fb_friend_cache, :source => :fb_user
end

class FbFriendCache < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fb_user, :class_name=>"User"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first define the `facebook_friends_cache` association:

```
has_many :facebook_friend_cache, :class_name => "FacebookFriendCache"
```

Then you need to define the `:through` association after that:

```
has_many :fb_friends, :through => :facebook_friend_cache, :foreign_key => :user_id
```

The `foreign_key` here needs to be the field that represents the id of the `User` object in the foreign table, so it needs to be `user_id` and not `fb_user_id`.

I would really give `facebook_friend_cache` a better name, too.

Comment: Would would you name it? I tried it, fyi the model is actually "FbFriendCache" it errors with Could not find the association :fb_friend_cache in model User

Comment: You need to define the :fb_friend_cache association before attempting to reference it in another association.

Comment: Ryan, isn't that what's happening above?

Comment: No, you've not defined the original :fb_friend_cache association before you try to reference it in your `fb_friends` association. Which is exactly what I explained in my answer!

Comment: The `:through` option in a `has_many` association must reference a previously defined association.

Comment: @RyanBigg, `foreign_key` property is ignored for `has_many :through` associations.